# Sharepoint Webpart in a MasterPage

Tags: sharepoint

I created a Custom webpart in which **on user logged on it has to check whether the user entry is there in a Custom list, if exists redirect to the accessed page.**

im writing in  OnPreRender(EventArgs e)....when i place this webpart in a page..it is perfectly working...**But, when placed in a masterpage it is not working**.....

im not getting if i'm placing the webpart in a wrong place.

Please do help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We need to see *how* you're placing the webpart in the masterpage to be able to help

Comment: Also does it really need to be a WebPart?  An asp.net control would seem to be less work to get the functionality you desire.

Comment: Can you please post the most essential code of your "protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)" method

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't place web parts on master pages. We struggled with that for a while trying to solve our navigation issues.